# Can I rotate a spinner? Androidstudio

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

simple question I cant find the answer anywhere, is there a way to rotate a spinner, without rotating screen or anything just create a spinner which is rotated 90 degrees?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On API Level 11+, you are welcome to rotate any `View` via [`android:rotation` in your layout XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation) or [`setRotation()` in Java](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29). Whether this will give you something that your users will like, I cannot say.

Comment: Just one more thing, this will rotate the spinner but not the dropdown menu...how would I manage that... a custom arrayadapter of some sort?

Comment: @javipasku: Um... I have no idea. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can try something like this -

```
           RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            // Adding the time needed to rotate the image
            animation.setDuration(250);

            // Set the animation to stop after reaching the desired position. Without this it would return to the original state.
            animation.setFillAfter(true);

           //Then set the animation to your view
            view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: That will rotate the pixels, but the touch area will not rotate. Hence, `RotateAnimation` is only really good for non-interactive widgets.